# Why function fourcc in opencv use 4 characters as arguments instead string?

Tags: c++, opencv

Why does the static member function `fourcc` in `VideoWriter` class use 4 characters as arguments instead of a string?

In C++, `cv::VideoWriter::fourcc` is used like:

```
VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
```

But I think

```
VideoWriter::fourcc("MJPG")
```

would be better.

I'm just curious because I've never seen function form like this.

Comment: Probably some historic reason + since you always need exactly 4 characters, the function doesn't need to validate the string length etc.

Comment: It's a four character code, so constructing it from four characters makes sense. The implementation is a single line of code, and it's rather difficult to provide wrong input (as opposed to your `char const*` -- how much code would you need to handle all of them, and then test it all?). | "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" seems to fit here, given that in over a decade noone seems to have felt it enough of an issue to make a pull request. (And in the scope of a computer vision library, a utility function in a utility module like this is insignificant)

Comment: you can write a simple function or macro according to your needs, that accepts a string and computes the fourcc integer value by splitting the string to 4 chars and calling VideoWriter::fourcc. Not sure whether you can even write a macro that replaces a given string by the 4 character and a comma during compile time. Like VideoWriter::fourcc(FOURCC_MACRO(abcd)) => VideoWriter::fourcc('a','b','c','d')